# When sending test notifications from azure push notifications it remove all device registrations

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I have register device token with tag when user login in to the application. After that when i send test notification from azure push notifications hub registered device ids is removed automatically. I am surprised of this type behavior. I have searched a lot, All are say that cause of setting wrong provision profiles setup or wrong certificate uploaded in to the azure notification hub but I have checked multiple times in my application. Certificates and provisioning profiles are in fine. Please suggest any idea of cause of this behavior.

Comment: Is your notification at least being delivered?

Comment: I haven't receive any notification but in azure at first time when I am sending it shows 1 successes and when I tried second time it shows 0 successes.

Comment: You probably are having a validation problem, where the tool itself clean the problematic tokens. This is an usual practice to help developers to keep the tokens up to date. Please check why your notifications are not being sent. Root cause.

Comment: So this type of behavior is the cause of device token issue or tag issue. If device token in wrong format we can get this type of behavior right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation about Notification Hubs **Device Registration**:

> It is important to note that **registrations are transient**. Similar to the PNS handles that they contain, registrations expire. **You can set the time to live for a registration on the Notification Hub, up to a maximum of 90 days. This limit means that they must be periodically refreshed**, and also that they should not be the only store for important information. This automatic expiration also simplifies cleanup when your mobile application is uninstalled.

For more details, you could refer to [Registration Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530747.aspx).

Additionally, as [Push notifications with Azure Notification Hubs: Frequently asked questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq#monitoring-and-troubleshooting) mentioned as follows:

> Notification Hubs cleans them up as it receives PNS feedback about expired or invalid registrations.

Comment: How can I validate device token is valid or not.

Comment: You could use azure portal for sending push notifications or leverage azure push notifications SDK for sending notifications and try to find whether you could retrieve the error message, for more details, you could refer to [Sending Push Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#sending-push-notifications).

Comment: Also, you could  follow the instructions from your specific platform about communicating with your PNS directly to find the detailed response from your PNS to narrow this issue. For APNs, you could refer to [Communicating with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1).